# Search for key inside dictionary and print values- Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks a little like this:

```
var index = {
  "Italian": [
    {
      "name": "Il Brigante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ],
  "Mexican": [
    {
      "name": "Cosme",
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ]
}
```

I also have a search bar that people can enter queries into. What I want to do is take the query and search for it inside `index`.

Example: search = `"italian"`, results = `{"name": "Il Brigante", "rating": "5.0"}, {"name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante", "rating": "5.0"}`

Is that kind of search possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much in advance. Happy 4th!

Cheers,
Theoi

Comment: What about `Giardino Doro Ristorante`?

Comment: _"Does anyone know how to do something like this?"_ - this is not a question. _It's a feature reuqest_.

Comment: is search is accurate or not. For example ital or italian?

Comment: @nikhil sorry edited my question!!

Comment: @SarathKumar im going for exact. do you think its easier if i dont?

Answer (score 2):

You can try following

```js
var index = {
  "Italian": [{
      "name": "Il Brigante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ],
  "Mexican": [{
    "name": "Cosme",
    "rating": "5.0"
  }]
};

var search = "italian";


var results = Object.keys(index).reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (b.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()) {
    return a.concat(index[b]);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(results);
```

**May Be a Requirement Later!**

In case you want to for the partial match, you just need to replace

```
if (b.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()) {
```

with

```
if(b.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
```

For tweaking - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xxeC0WNSfuNRwaUUCMbo?p=preview)

Comment: have an awesome independence day if youre in the usa

Comment: @TheoStrauss - Thank you. Not from the usa, but moment for celebration for people residing there and for rest to relish. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use hasOwnProperty directly, but that will only return exact matches.  Simplest way is to loop through the index properties and look for a match and return the resulting value.

```js
var index = {
  "Italian": [
    {
      "name": "Il Brigante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ],
  "Mexican": [
    {
      "name": "Cosme",
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(index.hasOwnProperty('italian'));
console.log(index.hasOwnProperty('Italian'));
console.log(dictionarySearch('Italian', index));

function dictionarySearch(term, dictionary)
{
  var found = false;
  if (typeof dictionary === 'object') {
    for(property in dictionary) {
      if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (property.toLowerCase() === term.toLowerCase()) {
          found = dictionary[property];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out square-bracket-notation.

> This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime).

[Source with examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

Applying this to your problem:

```js
var index = {
  "Italian": [
    {
      "name": "Il Brigante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ],
  "Mexican": [
    {
      "name": "Cosme",
      "rating": "5.0"
    }
  ]
}

var query = "Italian"
var result = index[query]

console.log(index["Italian"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is no situation when we have indexes like 'itAlIaN'/ 'italian' / 'ITALIAN' so index is unique no matter if you have lower/upper case

```js
var index = {
    "Italian": [
        {
            "name": "Il Brigante",
            "rating": "5.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Giardino Doro Ristorante",
            "rating": "5.0"
        }
    ],
    "Mexican": [
        {
            "name": "Cosme",
            "rating": "5.0"
        }
    ]
}

// function to normalize index by having keys lowercase
function lowercaseIndex (obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var n = keys.length;
    var normalized = {};
    while (n--) {
        var key = keys[n];
        normalized[key.toLowerCase()] = obj[key];
    }

    return normalized;
}

index = lowercaseIndex(index);

function search(needle) {
    return index[needle.toLowerCase()] || "No results";
}

// tests
console.log(search('Italian')); // output: [{"name":"Il Brigante","rating":"5.0"},{"name":"Giardino Doro Ristorante","rating":"5.0"}]
console.log(search('italian')); // output: [{"name":"Il Brigante","rating":"5.0"},{"name":"Giardino Doro Ristorante","rating":"5.0"}]
console.log(search('iTaLiAn')); // output: [{"name":"Il Brigante","rating":"5.0"},{"name":"Giardino Doro Ristorante","rating":"5.0"}]
console.log(search('mexican')); // output: [{"name":"Cosme","rating":"5.0"}]
console.log(search('English')); // output: "No results"
```